# String datatype in java

Tags: java, string, types

I was wondering, why is it "String" and not "string" when all other primitive data types are lowercase?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`String` isn't a primitive datatype - it's a class, a reference type. Now admittedly it's supported directly in the VM, and there are literals in the language - but it's still not a primitive type.

Comment: Closest answer. String is a class, which contains a lot of methods. You can, for instance, not invoke method calls on primitive data types. A String contains a value of a `byte[]` array: `{'v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e'}`

Comment: How could I have missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**It's not a primitive**, the String class is an object.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Your link is to an old version of Java.

Answer (score 2):

because it's a class and not a primitive data type. String is effectively an array of characters.

Comment: String *has* an array of characters. That's an important distinction! In Java, a String is an Object, not a char array

Comment: tried to keep it clean and simple. one could replace "is" by represents, covers, encompasses...

Comment: So why haven't you done that? 'Clean and simple' does not exclude 'incorrect'.

Answer (score 1):

Although the compiler has special support for `String`s, such as converting string literals into String instances, and performing String concatenation, String is not a primitive type, but a Class. By convention, class names begin in uppercase.

See the JLS section [Types,Values and Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html) for description of primitive types and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

String is a non premitive data type . You can use String as follows

```
int monthNumber = 2;
String monthName = "";
switch(monthNumber) {
    case 1:
        monthName = "January";
        break;
    case 2:
        monthName = "February";
        break;
    case 3:
        monthName = "March";
        break;
    case 4:
        monthName = "April";
        break;
}
System.out.println("The month is " + monthName);
```

Answer (score -1):

String in java borrows C syntax , the java compiler takes String as char array , so String is an abstract data type made by char array primitive data type

Answer (score -1):

String is class in java.lang pack but in.java al classes are also considered as data types so we can take string data type also.. 
We can.cal class is  user definednd  data type. This is because a user  can create a  class. 
     String a; 
A is variable  f the data type "string "

Answer (score -2):

String is a class in java and reference data type.String is a array of character so it is not a primitive data type.